# Text beside image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have different images with different widths but the same height, i want to display them inline with text next to each images, i did that but in the responsive screen it doesn't look nice, how can i fix that? and if there is another way to write this code other than mine please help, here is my code:

```css
.img{
  min-width: 30%;
  float: left;
  }
.text{
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 70%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150" />
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Doesn't look nice"* What do you want it to look like? Your question is to vague.  Also, your HTML is not valid. All of your `<div class="img">` tags are not closed.

Comment: i want the text below the image and they're closed

Comment: Why don't you create a container for each of the images?

Comment: Um, couldn't you just use an `:after` or `:before` pseudo element and position each one how you want it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use `figure` and `figcaption`.

Your question is not very precise, but this works well for me:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x150">
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-4">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
      <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snippet. It looks good in responsive screen as well.

Use Css:
    div{overflow:hidden}

```
<div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
     <figure>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/350x150">
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
     </figure>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4  col-xs-12">
     <figure>
       <img src="https://placehold.it/250x150">
       <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
    </figure>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-xs-12">
      <figure>
        <img src="https://placehold.it/300x150">
        <figcaption>Text</figcaption>
     </figure>
   </div>
</div>
```